# PDF library to extract text and image in Xamarin (Android)

Tags: gratis, android, library, pdf, c#

I'm a single developer trying to develop an Android app to convert PDF to ePub. I already have a prototype working for Windows in C#, and for that I used iText library.

Problem is, C# version of iText 7 cannot be used in Xamarin because there is no System.Drawing implementation in Mono. So I need a library that:

1. Extract chunks of text with its coordinates from PDF (pdf doesn't know words or sentences, that's why I used "chunks of text");
2. Extract font's name to get info about italic or bold;
3. Extract images with its coordinates from PDF;
4. Can work with Xamarin;
5. Is free.

I also make contact with syncfusion, but they told me that their product currently doesn't support all my requirements.

Comment: Unless your application is open source, iText is not free either.

Comment: @iPDFdev, yeah I'm aware of that, although I would like to keep the code closed, I'm willing to open source it, so aglp libraries can fulfill my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The [XFINIUM.PDF](https://xfiniumpdf.com/xfinium-pdf-crossplatform/xfinium-pdf-overview.html) library supports requirements 1, 2, 3, and 4.

Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops [XFINIUM.PDF](https://xfiniumpdf.com/xfinium-pdf-crossplatform/xfinium-pdf-overview.html).